# What is the difference between stripped binary and obfuscated binary

Tags: binary-analysis, obfuscation

I want to know the difference between stripped binary and obfuscated binary.

Answer (score 2):

**Stripped binary** is the one that compiled without debugging information [symbols, strings]. For gcc compiler it's -s flag.

**Obfuscated binary** is the one where developer deliberately chose to make part of it [or all] less readable and harder to analyse/debug/disassemble. 
Obfuscation can impact:

1. **code** - when author hide some parts of code sections and specific parts of executable code using cryptors/packers/various techniques of code polymorphism etc.
2. **resources** - when author apply various tehnniques of obfuscation (crypto/packing/custom modification) on data (strings, data, configuration etc.)
3. **complete binary** - when external executable/code used to completely hide presence of binary that should be hidden.

Comment: Well, _actually_ stripped usually means that the information was _removed_ afterward (which also matches the meaning of "to strip" in English) by means of `strip` or `objcopy` or similar.